# Доступ к файлу через приложение

Tags: c#

Доброе время суток. Скажите пожалуйста возможно ли такое реализовать: когда пользователь работает с файлом через приложение(в моем случае зашифровывает его) и сохраняет его, то уже доступ к этому файлу, его удаления можно только при вводе пароля, которые указал этот самый пользователь? То есть файл будет открыт только для чтения сторонним людям. Приложение пишется для того, если за компьютером работают несколько людей. Я уже думала про группу пользователей и администратора. Но не понимаю, как это делать. Спасибо) Приложение пишется на visual studio (windows forms)

Comment: Если файл зашифрован, то читать и изменять его сможет только тот, кто знает пароль. Но в любом случае удалить его может администратор. Ну, поставьте файлу атрибуты скрытый и системный, чтобы его сложнее было найти посторонним.

Comment: а в каком формате зашифрованный файл? `*.txt`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko файл любого формата зашифровывается

Comment: Бороться против администратора невозможно, он всегда может поменять права доступа и удалить файл. А против обыкновенных юзеров не проблема, просто настройте права на доступ к файлу в файловой системе.